# How to setup QOS?

Tags: networking, internet, adsl, dsl, qos

I have 2 PC

- PC**1** **download** large files all the time
- PC**2** **browser** internet some times like facebook

PC**2 can't** enter facebook because PC**1 download** large files all the time

I want router **give proitry to** PC**2**, How ?

My router like this https://www.tp-link.com/it/faq-537.html

Comment: What model router do you have? You should be looking for [Bandwidth Control](https://www.tp-link.com/fr-be/faq-194.html) settings

Comment: QoS isn't really what your looking for in this case, try using bandwidth restrictions instead and just limit PC1 from using all the download bandwidth.

Comment: I want PC1 useing all bandwidth when PC2 not connected

Comment: I want dynamic bandwidth not fixed

Comment: Incoming traffic is more difficult to control. By the time you see the traffic, it has already used your incoming bandwidth. If the traffic is TCP, you can slow down the outbound ACKs and police the incoming traffic. That will cause TCP to resend and think the connection is less reliable, so the sender will slow. For a connectionless protocol, you really have no control over incoming traffic. Business-grade routers will have good controls, to help do what you want.